# Shopify Create Order API

Tags: shopify

I used the Shopify API to create an order using my product's variantID.

For some reason, `line_item`s in orders created using the API always have `"vendor":"null"`. Whereas orders for the same variant created via the store returns the correct `vendor`.

Am I doing anything wrong?

```
URL: https://xxyy.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json

{   "order": {     
        "email": "ken@xxyy.com",   
        "fulfillment_status": "unfulfilled" , 
        "send_receipt": true,   
        "send_fulfillment_receipt": false,     
        "line_items": [{         
            "variant_id": 3866750123,     
            "quantity": 1       
        }]   
    } 
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get that sometimes too and it is truly crappy. If you create a line item using the API it seems you need to provide not only the product and variant ID, but also the **vendor**, as even if it exists in the product, that does not get picked up in the order creation process. A lot of Apps screw this up. Which screws up other Apps expecting good orders. And a it seems to me a good order should have the product vendor field set.

Comment: when you say `provide not only the product and variant ID, but also the *variant*`, what does the *variant* mean?

Comment: fixed typo.. sorry